# Play Store silently updates apps although auto-update is disabled

Tags: google-play-store, updates, privacy, xposed-framework, application-autoupdate

On my Samsung Galaxy Note 4, I have XPrivacy installed.  This tool tells me about newly installed and updated apps.

In the Google Play store settings, I've set my "App download preference" to "Ask me every time".  I've also set the "Auto-update apps" preference to "Don't auto-update apps".

Still, once every couple of days, XPrivacy informs me about random apps being updated.  Sometimes it's the Google Play store itself being updated.  Other times, it's other apps.  Usually, a bunch of apps are updated at the same time; therefore, I doubt it's some self-updating feature of those apps.

So, in sum:  I've tried to set things up so that the Google Play store doesn't update apps without asking or even informing me.

Why is Android ignoring my preference?

Security reasons?

I feel betrayed.  :(

Comment: Check which apps are updated. Most likely they are Samsung specific and they are updated by the "Galaxy Store" not Google Play Store.

Comment: Next time I'll get unwanted updates I'll post them here but these are definitively not Samsumg apps only. Examples I can remember include the Play Store itself and CamScanner

Comment: The Play Store and the play store support libraries are not apps and therefore are not affected by any "Do not update" policy. Especially the PS libraries even update over cellular even if you have set only to process updates via Wifi.